# Drupal 7 themeing

Tags: drupal-7, themes

Im new to Drupal theme'ing. Totally new. I managed to install the Omega 5 theme. I created my subtheme. But I'm like now what? I created the blocks that go in the regions where I want them. But now I need to start themeing the blocks. I need to start aligning the content int the regions. So two tasks I need to start with are:

1. Create a square around my block text in the user bar first zone. I have the block there. I have the content. I have the CSS. But I cannot just add it with the CKeditor on the block content. There are no template files created. I tried adding a div ID in the block on the content and adding the CSS to the global.css file. Nohting worked. I even cleared the cache. So where do I go this?
2. When I manage to learn how to style a block I have three of them in the user bar first zone. My theme is full width. It has 12 columns. I prefixed the zone with 9 columns as I have 3 blocks. I want the 3 blocks to appear horizontally aligned and to the right. I thought the prefix moved them to the right. My first block is not to the right but to the left. So where do I put this CSS?

Sorry to be so clueless but the Omega tutorials promise a WYSIWYG exprience but fail to deliver how. I get up to how to create the subtheme and then the tutorials end. I am an expert PHP developer but if I don't know where to put the PHP then it doesn't help much.

Comment: You can just add all your CSS to template.css that gets created in the subtheme

Comment: In your subtheme you must have style.css or you can create new css file and include in your page tpl. There you can write your css by selecting html class and id attributes